# IBM MQSeries Cache Queue Depth

Tags: websphere, ibm-mq

Current IBM MQSeries Queue Depth in our System is 150000.Because of Huge queue depth, IBM MQ Cache is getting Corrupted/Going down. Is there Something we can do to have Queue Manager hold current queue depth of 150000 given that IBM Recommended Queue depth is 5000?

Comment: What is "IBM MQ Cache"? IBM MQ is quite happy with queues that have 150000 messages on them. If it wasn't, it wouldn't let you do it. The DEFAULT maximum queue depth of 5000 is only a suggestion, you are allowed to change that. Please update your question with more details about the corruption you see - how does it manifest? And more information about whatever it is that is "going down" - what errors do you see and so on. For example, what is in the queue manager error log? Are there any FDCs?

Comment: Adding to @MoragHughson point, you need to find out the reason for messages piling up in the first place? It appears that there is no application consuming messages from the queue. Applications must be desgined to process messages quickly to avoid message pile up.

Comment: Any update on this?